# Custom title format in iTerm2 / Terminal

Tags: spacemacs, terminal-emacs, term

I've been looking all over but none of the guides I saw worked for me.

I am trying to have the title of Spacemacs to show a custom format, namely the current project's name (the current folder's name).

I am using Iterm2, so I want the tabs to represent the directories.

Currently, the title says `emacs (emacs-25.2)` which isn't very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.spacemacs` file (`SPC f e d`), under `dotspacemacs/init`, change the `dotspacemacs-frame-title-format` line to:

```
dotspacemacs-frame-title-format "%t"
```

That's the current *projectile* project's name, which is not the same as the current directory name.  Not sure if there's a format string for "current directory", so you'd probably have to write some elisp if you wanted exactly that.  There's also `"%f"` though, which is the current file path.